# Akagami no Shirayukihime letters or font?

Tags: snow-white-with-the-red-hair

What type of letters or font is used in Clarines? I've been searching for it and I can't seem to find an answer.

Here is a screenshot of Shirayuki's Clarines Castle "pass tag/ID" from episode 6. I can somewhat read the "Clarines K • D Wistal Court" part.

[image: Shirayuki's Clarines ID]

And can you please link where can I download it?

Sorry for my bad English. It's not my first language. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, the website for Hakusensha's *LaLa* (the magazine in which *Akagami no Shirayuki-hime* is serialized) has [a nifty little thing](http://www.hakusensha.co.jp/lala/entertainment/akagami.html) where you can enter your date of birth and your name, and it invents a life for you somewhere in the world of *Akagami*. (For example, I am apparently a "nervous boy awaiting the incipient start of the tournament of arms in Yurikana".)

As a bonus, it also displays your name in Clarines script. I used this to extract the Clarines glyphs. Here they are:

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]
[image: e]
[image: f]
[image: g]
[image: h]
[image: i]
[image: j]
[image: k]
[image: l]
[image: m]
[image: n]
[image: o]
[image: p]
[image: q]
[image: r]
[image: s]
[image: t]
[image: u]
[image: v]
[image: w]
[image: x]
[image: y]
[image: z]

Turning this into a genuine font is left as an exercise for the reader.

If you're looking for a name for this, there isn't really one; Japanese sites just call it クラリネス文字, meaning "Clarines letters".